# editing attribute of setter / getter

Tags: python

I am making a game with a camera whose position is its top-left. I wanted to have the behaviour such that I set the camera's position to the player and the player would be at the center of my screen.

```py
camera.pos = player.pos
```

Then I made a scrolling camera that I only want to affect the camera's x

```py
camera.pos.x = player.pos.x
```

The problem here is that it gets the getter and then overrides its x position, and doesn't effect the actual position. How do I get the above behaviour? Thank you.

Below is the important parts of the system.

```py
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x: float | int = 0, y: float | int = 0):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    
    def __sub__(self, other: any) -> Vector:
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return Vector(self.x - other, self.y - other)
        if isinstance(other, Vector):
            return Vector(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, pos: Vector = Vector(),...):
        self._pos = pos
...
    @property
    def pos(self):
        """
        The current position of the camera.
        """
        return self._pos + Display.center

    @pos.setter
    def pos(self, pos: Vector):
        self._pos = pos - Display.center
```

Comment: I can't understand what is your actual problem. Can you clarify? Please show what is your current output and what is the one you expect

Comment: That's just the way it works.  Perhaps `pos` should be a member rather than a property.

Answer (score 0):

I guess @Tim Roberts was right. I ended up, creating a private and public attribute and updating the private attribute once per frame. Thank you.